# Tkinter: Using ttkthemes on a Toplevel window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk
import sqlite3
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#Root window configuration
root = tk.ThemedTk()
root.get_themes()
root.set_theme('plastik')


root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(height=False, width=False)


def adminlogin_function():
    # adminlogin_window configuration

    # adminlogin_window = Toplevel()
    adminlogin_window =  tk.Toplevel()
    adminlogin_window.get_themes()
    adminlogin_window.set_theme('plastik')
    
    adminlogin_window.geometry("700x400")
    
    # Widgets on adminlogin_window
    admin_username_label = Label(adminlogin_window, text="Username", fg="black")
    admin_username_label.place(x=388, y=135)
    admin_username_entry = Entry(adminlogin_window, border=2)
    admin_username_entry.place(x =490 , y =135, width = 85)
    admin_pass_label = Label(adminlogin_window, text="Password", fg="black")
    admin_pass_label.place(x = 388, y= 180)
    admin_pass_entry = Entry(adminlogin_window, border=2,show="*")
    admin_pass_entry.place(x =490 , y =180, width = 85)
    admin_login_button = Button(adminlogin_window, text="Login")
    admin_login_button.place(x = 430, y= 230, width=100)
    adminlogin_window.mainloop()
adminlogin_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Admin Login", command = adminlogin_function)
adminlogin_button.place(x=250, y=160, width = 200)
```

How to use ttkthemes on a Toplevel() window? It is working fine for the root window but it is just not working for a top-level window. I cannot find any documentation for this

Comment: ttkthemes works for any ttk widget in the Toplevel, you just don't have any of these widgets in your toplevel. Use `ttk.Label`, `ttk.Entry`, ... instead.

Comment: can you please show me how i create the Toplevel() like i did for root?  this throws an error that tk does not have Toplevel() `adminlogin_window =  tk.Toplevel()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to manually do anything, once theme is applied to main window, all the other windows and widgets inherit the theme if you prefix it (import it from) with `ttk`, like:

```
ttk.Label(...)
ttk.Entry(....)
ttk.Button(...)
```

And also, `adminlogin_window =  tk.Toplevel()` shoudnt have `tk` as your `tk` is actually `from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk`, so just say:

```
adminlogin_window =  Toplevel() #this uses toplevel from tkinter
```

Your function would be:

```
def adminlogin_function():
    # adminlogin_window configuration
    adminlogin_window =  Toplevel()    
    adminlogin_window.geometry("700x400")
    
    # Widgets on adminlogin_window
    admin_username_label = ttk.Label(adminlogin_window, text="Username")
    admin_username_label.place(x=388, y=135)
    admin_username_entry = ttk.Entry(adminlogin_window)
    admin_username_entry.place(x =490 , y =135, width = 85)
    admin_pass_label = ttk.Label(adminlogin_window, text="Password")
    admin_pass_label.place(x = 388, y= 180)
    admin_pass_entry = ttk.Entry(adminlogin_window,show="*")
    admin_pass_entry.place(x =490 , y =180, width = 85)
    admin_login_button = ttk.Button(adminlogin_window, text="Login")
    admin_login_button.place(x = 430, y= 230, width=100)
```

Notice here I've removed `fg` and `border` option from the widget because `ttk` does not support those option for their widgets, it's rather tiresome to change those. I've also removed `adminlogin_window.mainloop()` as it's not necessary for `Toplevel` to have `mainloop()`.