# How to use a theme on all windows in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, ttkthemes

I'm making a GUI in Tkinter and want the sun valley theme (https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme) to effect all my windows.

When I run my code only the first window in this case the Test class has the theme, when I click the button and run my next window Main the theme isn't applied.

I've tried it with and without Test.destroy(), not using sv_ttk.use_dark_theme() in Main() and I have also tried switching the theme back and forth with no change.

Here are two screen shots of both windows afterwards is my code:

Test() window:

[image: Test() window]

Main() window:

[image: Main() window]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sv_ttk

class Test(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        sv_ttk.use_dark_theme()

        self.geometry('250x150')
        self.title("Test")
        self.resizable(0,0)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)

        testButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Press me!", command=lambda : self.newWindow()).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)   

    def newWindow(self):
        self.newWindow = Main()
        Test.destroy()
                    
class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        sv_ttk.use_dark_theme()

        self.geometry('1200x800')
        self.title("Main")

        self.resizable(0,0)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


        self.test = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text="testing", style="Toggle.TButton")
        self.test.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
        

    
if __name__ =="__main__":
    Test=Test()
    Test.mainloop()
```

Comment: Every time you create a new instance of `Tk()` (including subclasses thereof), you create an independent GUI environment, entirely unrelated to the previous one in any way.  Use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows that are part of the existing environment.

Comment: Hi this fixed it, with this knowledge this page is a good read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64062134/tkinter-using-ttkthemes-on-a-toplevel-window

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `tk.Tk()` for both Test and Main classes, which creates separate Tkinter instances for each window. what you can do instead is you should use `tk.Toplevel()` for additional windows after the initial main window. This worked for me and should work for you too:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sv_ttk

class Test(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    sv_ttk.use_dark_theme()

    self.geometry('250x150')
    self.title("Test")
    self.resizable(0,0)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)

    testButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Press me!", command=lambda : 
    self.newWindow())
    testButton.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)   

def newWindow(self):
    self.newWindow = Main(self)  
    self.withdraw()  
             
class Main(tk.Toplevel):  
 def __init__(self, master=None):  
    super().__init__(master)
    sv_ttk.use_dark_theme()

    self.geometry('1200x800')
    self.title("Main")
    self.resizable(0,0)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    self.test = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text="testing", style="Toggle.TButton")
    self.test.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close) 

def on_close(self):
    self.master.deiconify() 
    self.destroy()  

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = Test()
    app.mainloop()
```